# How to sort and subset a python dictionary with compound key?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I got a Python dictionary with compound key (Pri_key, Sec_key) and value:

```
(123, 456): 45
(123, 457): 90
(124, 234): 70
(125, 87): 3
(125, 103): 56
(125, 897): 34
```

How to sort the value in descending order on each "Pri_key", and list the corresponding "Sec_key" accordingly?
The expected result:

```
123: 457 456
124: 234
125: 103 897 83
```

Comment: Break it down into small steps and write an algorithm in plain English. What part are you having trouble with? What have you tried so far? (PS - you mean _ascending_ order?)

Comment: Are you trying to print the results or store them in a sorted data structure?

Comment: I try to print the results as the dictionary are already computed.
And I don't know how to select the key & value by the Pri_key only.

Comment: I need list the Sec_key according to the descending order of the key pair's value under the same Pri_key

Comment: You don't select the key and value by only the primary key. That is not unique, hence your use of a compound key. If you want selection by primary key only, you have set your dict up incorrectly.

Comment: The dictionary is generated after the map and sort phase in mapreduce. I need to use compound or composted key due to the subject requirement. The Pri_key is the user, and the Sec_key is other user, and the value is their similarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is the original sort.  After that, you can `groupby` on the primary key.  To construct the sort, you can key off a tuple of `(<primary-key>, -<value>)` (the negative is to sort the values that have the same primary key in descending order):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
sorted_keys = sorted(original_dict, key=lambda key: (key[0], -original_dict[key]))
for primary_key, key_group in groupby(sorted_keys, key=itemgetter(0)):
    print(primary_key, [key[1] for key in key_group])
```

And, of course, if you can *print* the keys, then you can use it to construct a dictionary (or any other datastructure) using the results :-).

Here's a demo from my terminal:

```
>>> original_dict = {
... (123, 456): 45,
... (123, 457): 90,
... (124, 234): 70,
... (125, 87): 3,
... (125, 103): 56,
... (125, 897): 34
... }
>>>
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> sorted_keys = sorted(original_dict, key=lambda key: (key[0], -original_dict[key]))
>>> for primary_key, key_group in groupby(sorted_keys, key=itemgetter(0)):
...     print(primary_key, [key[1] for key in key_group])
... 
(123, [457, 456])
(124, [234])
(125, [103, 897, 87])
```

Comment: I tried this solution. However, it seems the sort by value is missed. So, the Sec_key is simply its key sort order.
In addition, both Pri_key and Sec_key are sorted in string order ( 1, 11, 111, 2, ...) , and I need them in numeric order.

Comment: @PaulYu -- It should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, mgilson. Will work on to get the format (no comma, just ":" after the Pri_key) I need.

Comment: `print('{}: {}'.format(primary_key, ', '.join(key[1] for key in key_group))` should do the trick.

Comment: How do I subset the dictionary so that only Top 10 value Sec_key are shown after each Pri_key ??

Comment: @PaulYu -- You can truncate the `key_group`, e.g. `key_group = itertools.islice(key_group, 0, 10)` and then do the printing as above (of course, you'll need to `import` `itertools.islice` before you can do that.

Comment: Everythings works, except the "Pri_key" still sort as string... not like integer..  my result:    
0: 434 509 656 40 58 79 210 312 699 740
1: 365 371 606 24 421 530 543 549 638 642
10: 169 58 91 269 397 451 543 632 724 740

Comment: @PaulYu -- Then you're probably _storing_ the Primary key as a string rather than an integer.  You can modify the sort key function to convert the string to an int `lambda key: (int(key[0]), -original_dict[key])`.

Comment: Bingo... 
Much appreciated your patient and prompt response. 
Your guidance save me hours of work.
Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

We'll need to iterate over the keys and then build another dictionary with the second value of the compound key as part of a list that this new dictionary points to. We then sort the values of the new dictionary. Observe.

Suppose your original dictionary is called `d`.

```
k = {} # Our new dictionary
for key in d.keys():
    (Pri_key, Sec_key) = key
    try:
        k[Pri_key].append(Sec_key)
    except KeyError:
        k[Pri_key] = [Sec_key] # Make a new list if the new key doesn't exist

# Make a list of sorted keys
keys = [key for key in d.keys()]
keys.sort()
for key in keys:
    list = d[key]
    list.sort()
    print(key + ':' + list)
```

There you have it.

Answer (score 0):

One-liner:

```
sorted((k,sorted(v)) for k,v in functools.reduce(lambda d,k: (d[0],d[0].setdefault(k[0],[]).append(k[1])),d.keys(),({},None))[0].items())
```

Clearer:

```
def sort(d):
    new = {k0: [] for k0,_ in d.keys()}
    for k0,k1 in d.keys():
        new[k0].append(k1)
    new_sorted = {k: sorted(v) for k,v in new.items()}
    return sorted(new_sorted.items())
```

Comment: You could use a `new = collections.defaultdict(list)` rather than the dict comprehension.  That said, I don't think this gives what OP wants since nowhere to you include the values from `d` in your sort.  I think you'd need `sorted(v, key=lambda secondary: d[key, secondary], reverse=True)` in your `new_sorted` dict comprehension to get what OP wants.

Comment: Excellent suggestions. I'll tweak the unsilly version.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Python 2.7:

```
>>> d = {(123, 456): 45, (123, 457): 90, (124, 234): 70, (125, 87): 3, (125, 103): 56, (125, 897): 34}
>>> items = d.items()
>>> items.sort(key=lambda e: e[1], reverse=True)
>>> items
[((123, 457), 90), ((124, 234), 70), ((125, 103), 56), ((123, 456), 45), ((125, 897), 34), ((125, 87), 3)]
>>> keys = set(map(lambda e: e[0][0], items))
>>> keys
set([123, 124, 125])
>>> for k in keys:
...     print '%d: %s' % (k, ' '.join([str(e[0][1]) for e in items if e[0][0] == k]))
...
123: 457 456
124: 234
125: 103 897 87
```